# How to highlight model or category names in scientific text (if they are ordinary words)?

Tags: meaning, quotation-marks, style-manuals, italics

For example, there are two sentences

1. The government is considering that the crisis will follow a soft scenario ...
2. Dr. Jones has calculated soft and hard crisis scenarios. The input data was ...

In the first case, *soft* is just an adjective (not about a chair, but still one of the usual meanings).

In the second, *soft* and *hard* are, of course, also real features. But in addition they are the names of the models and they are used in this way in the following text. I have a suspicion that they should be set off. Italic (like terms or emphases)? quotation marks (as non-standard(?) sense)? capital initial (as for proper names)? Something else or nothing?

Comment: If neither "soft" nor "hard" have been previously referenced before #2, you should probably enclose them in "scare quotes". But this is all a matter of typographic / stylistic ***choices***.

Comment: I have no idea what a "soft" or "hard" scenario is in this context. Even if you set them off, it wouldn't help me in the least in terms of understanding what they mean. Assuming anybody else in your audience is the same as me, you need to define them in some way. Simply setting them off will only draw attention to the fact that the meaning isn't understood. So, you *can* set them off, but you need to do more than just that.